# Insert Data into Mysql from PHP from a nested foreach loop

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, json

I'm trying to enter data fetched from a json into a database. I have fetched the data as a multidimensional array and used a foreach loop to loop through the arrays.

I'm trying to insert this data into a mysql database but I keep getting an error **Error: Field 'summary' doesn't have a default value**.

My database table is called articles in a database called tracking and has the following fields: **article_id, url, domain, favicon, title, summary, likes, tweets, plusones, image, category**

my php file is called **json_parser.php** and it is as follows

```
<?php
define('DB_NAME', 'tracking');
define('DB_USER', 'xxxxxxxxxxx');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'xxxxxxxxx');
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');

$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

if (!$link){
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

$db_selected = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $link);

if(!$db_selected){
    die('Cannot use '. DB_NAME . ': ' .mysql_error());
}

$url = "http://digitalrand.net/api/url_data/?key=abacus&pass=aba123cuxza%";
$json = file_get_contents($url);
$obj = json_decode($json, true);

foreach($obj as $article_array){

    $url = $article_array['url'];
    $domain = $article_array['domain'];
    $favicon = $article_array['favicon'];
    $title = $article_array['title'];
    $category = $article_array['category'];
    echo $category . "<br>";
    echo $domain . "<br>";
    echo $favicon . "<br>";
    echo $title . "<br>";
    echo $url . "<br>";

    $sql = 'INSERT INTO articles '.
               '(url, domain, favicon, title) '.
               'VALUES ( "$url", "$domain","$favicon","$title" )';
    if (mysql_query($sql)){
        echo "success.......";
    }


    if(!mysql_query($sql)){
       die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    $large_summary = $article_array['summary'];
    foreach ($large_summary as $summary){
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO articles(summary) VALUES('$summary')");
        echo "$summary <br>";
    }
    $images = $article_array['images'];
    foreach ($images as $image){        
        $image_first= reset($image);
        echo $image_first;
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO articles(image) VALUES($image_first)");
        echo "<img src=$image_first>";
    }
    $social_shares = $article_array['social_shares'];

    foreach($social_shares as $social_share=>$include){
        echo $social_share . ": " . $include . "<br>";
    }

    $entities = $article_array["entities"];

    foreach($entities as $entity_cat=>$entities_arr){
        foreach($entities_arr as $key=>$entity){
            echo $entity_cat.' >> '.$entity. "<br>";
        } 
    }
}   

?>
```

How do I loop through the array items and display them on appropriate fields

Comment: what is the data type of summary and looks like its set to NOT NULL so make it NULL.

Comment: I've tried dropping the column and reinserting it again but it sets itself to null by default i.e. **ALTER TABLE  `articles` ADD  `summary` TEXT NOT NULL ;**

Comment: Do you really wan't to insert rows without summary but with `url, domain, favicon, title` and other one with `summary` or `image` but without others fields? Because it's that you are doing!

Comment: more over for string data u need to enclose them in quotes before adding them to DB.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty ... I have corrected that.

Comment: @JoDev ... I also want to insert data into the other rows its only that the loops are just too many and I've never worked with so many loops before. I figured I will figure it one step at a time

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty ... check a comment I've added to JoDev's answer below. The db is getting fed actual variable names instead of variable content

Comment: did u enclose them in quotes something as `'$summary'`?

Comment: can u echo the query and see what u get and that directly on mysql

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty. This is what the query returns **INSERT INTO articles (url, domain, favicon, title) VALUES ( "$url", "$domain","$favicon","$title" )**

Comment: change ur sql query and use it as `$sql = "INSERT INTO articles (url, domain, favicon, title) VALUES ( '$url', '$domain','$favicon','$title')";`

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty. That worked. I'm creating a child table for summaries and images as advised by JoDev below

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have an error in your code :

`foreach ($large_summary as $summary){
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO articles(summary) VALUES($summary)");
        echo "$summary 
";
}`

`foreach ($large_summary as $summary){
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO articles(summary) VALUES('$summary')");
        echo "$summary 
";
}`

Then, keep in mind that you are INSERTING row with only `(url, domain, favicon, title)` fields, and then some rows with only `(summary)` and then other one with only `(image)`.
I think you wan't to insert into the same row no?

Then if you wan't to make it works, you have to set a default value :

```
ALTER TABLE `articles` CHANGE `summary` `summary` TEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL;
```

**[EDIT to  answer to the Mutuma comment]**

Your database isn't set correctly. You have few sumaries for one group of `(url, domain, favicon, title)`.

So you have to create another table, like `summaries` with `(id, ref_article, summary)`...
And it hte same for `images`!

Please reconsider the base structure.

Comment: Yes I do want to insert into the same row no

Comment: I have set all fields to default to none. However I'm getting an error **Error: Duplicate entry 'url' for key 'url'** and the data being fed into the db is the variable names not the content of the variables

Comment: **Don't** set it to "none", but `NULL DEFAULT NULL` or `DEFAULT 'something'` but not `none`. Read MySQL doc to understand DEFAULT values!

Comment: ...my bad, I had set it to NULL, The error I was getting was because I was trying to save a record twice as the url is setto unique, However I went and used the child tables, images, social_shares  and summaries and associated them to the parent table articles but I'm having a problem a inserting data into the child tables via the parent table,articles